# Tell me the namespaces and references to be added to use CopyToDataTable method in linq for returning dataset

Tags: linq-to-sql

I cant see the System.data.datatableextensions in the reference list and hence not getting intellisence for CopyToDataTable method to return dataset from linq through aweb service.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace:  System.Data

Assembly:  System.Data.DataSetExtensions (in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx

--Jocke

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the documentation of the [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx) method you will see at the very top the name of the assembly you need to reference. It is System.Data.DataExtensions.dll . If you don't have the documentation installed on your machine, you can find it simply by googling for CopyToDataTable. It is the first answer returned